# WordPress API v2 get news for all categories

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

How to get all categories and 2 news for each? You can get all categories, but this is inconvenient. You have to do it later `categories.map { it.getNewsForCategories() }` It is not comfortable. I want to get the data to display on the main page in one request.

I tried to get the first 2 posts from all categories, but that doesn't work.